# Je fais de mon mieux: what is the 'de'?

Tags: de

I have come across the phrase 'Je fais de mon mieux' as the French equivalent of 'I do my best'. What grammatical role is being played by the 'de'?

Answer (score 4):

'De' does not mean anything special here. This is an idiomatic construction.

You have a similar construction in the following sentence :

> Il fait du mieux qu'il peut.

Maybe this is related to other ways to describe the way/manner to do something :

> - Il marche de façon étrange
> - Il écrit de la main gauche

Comment: Doesn't 'de' in these cases indicates a way of doing things as opposed to a direct object complement?

Comment: @vc74 Exactly, you can even add a direct object in the sentence : Il fait **cela** de son mieux.

Comment: *de son mieux* → to the best of his abilities

Answer (score 2):

This is an idiomatic turn in which the preposition can't be analyzed semantically in too accurate a manner. Its meaning is comparable to that  in  "faire des pieds et des mains", for instance (roughly, "avec").

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) 4. La modalité est une manière d'être ou de se comporter.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mieux)

> **II.** − [Superl. de bien]
> **B.** − Substantif
> **b)** [*Le mieux* est précédé d'une prép.]
> − [de] De + adj. poss. + mieux. Avec la meilleure volonté, en déployant toutes ses resources.
> ►  Aider, consoler, se défendre, expliquer, répondre de son mieux.
> ♦ Je m'efforçai de les réciter de mon mieux, de les parer de tout le prestige du débit (Florian,Fables, 1792, p.6).
> ♦ L'on s'exterminait, ma foi, comme on pouvait. On faisait de son mieux (Hugo,Légende, t.5, 1877, p.983).

It is reckoned with as an adverbial locution.

> [découvrir le français](https://langue-francaise.tv5monde.com/decouvrir/dictionnaire/d/de%20son%20mieux) adv.    Aussi bien que l'on peut, du mieux possible.

Others treat the form in which is added the verb "faire" as a verbal locution.

> [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_de_son_mieux) Locution verbale
> faire de son mieux \fɛʁ də sɔ̃ mjø\ intransitif (se conjugue → voir la conjugaison de faire)
> [sens] Faire le maximum pour parvenir à un résultat.
> ♦ Sois donc attentif, mon garçon ; sois docile ; fais de ton mieux ce que tu dois faire. Dans la vie, tout est là ! — (Hector Malot, Sans famille, 1878)
> ♦ Léo faisait de son mieux pour me décontrister. — (Gilles Barbedette, Le métromane, 1985, page 142)
> ♦   Quand je fus assuré que le silence était bien revenu, je saisis un canif et fis de mon mieux pour tenter de m’entailler la jambe droite.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une réponse à une question sous-entendue  'de quelle manière' ou 'de quelle façon'.
Si on l'exprime par une question préalable on voit mieux l'articulation:
**De quelle manière** tu compte le faire ? : Je vais le faire **de** mon mieux
**De quelle main** tu écris ?  : J'écris **de** la main gauche
**De quelle façon** il marche ? : Il marche **de** façon étrange.
etc.
Le '**De quel**' exprime un choix à faire dans une liste ouverte et le '**de xx**' exprime ce choix.